# Checking tag colors

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have an array `vs.tags` which may contain **hundreds** of objects, and a smaller array `coloredTags` which only contains up to **3** objects.

The goal is to efficiently check the `ids` in `coloredTags` to the `ids` in `vs.tags` and perform some action.

This is what I have so far:

```
var coloredTags = ColoredTagFactory.retrieveColoredTags();
console.log('coloredTags = ', coloredTags); // = 2
console.log('vs.tags     = ', vs.tags);     // = 25
var numColors = coloredTags.length;

for (var i=0; i<vs.tags.length; i++) {
    if (numColors === 1) {
        if (vs.tags[i].term_id === coloredTags[0].id) {
            vs.tags[i].border1 = true;
        }
    }
    else if (numColors === 2) {
        if (vs.tags[i].term_id === coloredTags[1].id) {
            vs.tags[i].border2 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to write this? Some sort of nested loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method of rewriting it could be checking `if (numColors === 1)` and likewise for 2 before you enter the loop.

You should also store `coloredTags[#].id` outside the loop.

```
if (numColors === 1) {
    var coloredTagId = coloredTags[numColors - 1].id;
    for (var i=0; i<vs.tags.length; i++) {
        if (vs.tags[i].term_id === coloredTagId) {
            vs.tags[i].border1 = true;
        }
    }
}
else if (numColors === 2) {
    var coloredTagId = coloredTags[numColors - 1].id;
    for (var i=0; i<vs.tags.length; i++) {
        if (vs.tags[i].term_id === coloredTagId) {
            vs.tags[i].border2 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

This should save you some performance, as `numColors` cannot change in the loop so there's no need to check the value of it *each iteration*, and you grab the `coloredTags[#].id` value once instead of each iteration.

---

Another thing you could consider, which may be more beneficial, is to rewrite it to call a function when a match is found:

```
if (numColors >= 1 && numColors <= 2) { // change 1/2 as needed
    var coloredTagId = coloredTags[numColors - 1].id;
    for (var i=0; i<vs.tags.length; i++) {
        if (vs.tags[i].term_id === coloredTagId) {
            someFunction(vs.tags[i], coloredTagId);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in `someFunction`:

```
function someFunction(vsTagsObject, coloredTagId) {
    switch (coloredTagId) {
        case 1:
            vsTagsObject.border1 = true;
            break;
        case 2:
            vsTagsObject.border2 = true;
            break;
    }
}
```

Note: I'm not an angular.js guy, or a Javascript expert, so the above may need tweaking to work.

This should help separate responsibilities of your code, and make it easier to maintain.

Comment: Thanks! Going with solution 1 for now, I need to get solution 2 to work

Comment: @LeonGaban Well I accidentally omitted the `break;` statements on solution 2, if that was hurting you. Glad I could help! :)

Comment: Hmm, I added those in too, but for some reason it kinda funky still... oh well